# Filtering of an array in a list type data.table column

Tags: arrays, r, list, filter, data.table

I'm trying to solve a problem in which for a new route (of a truck) that I just found, I check if that route was already a part of a previous route I have. For instance, assume my stored routes are in datatable `routelist` and `node_list` refers to the stored routes. I want to check the rows in which route (5,6,7,8) is part of.

```
library(data.table)
routelist=data.table(id=c(1:3),node_list=list(c(1:6),c(4:7),c(1:10)))
item<-c(5:8)
routelist[sum(item%in%unlist(packlist$node_list))==length(item)]
```

For the above check, all three rows are returned however only the third row should be returned. I could do it with the following for loop, but it s not fast and does not take order into account (and there should be a way to do it in a better way). The order of nodes in `item` is important and the list does not need to be consecutive i.e. item could be `c(5,7,8)` and should be returned in 3rd row while `c(5,8,7)` shouldnt return.

```
for(i in 1:3)
{
  if(sum(item%in%unlist(packlist[i]$node_list))==length(item))
    print(routelist[i])
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues with OP's `data.table` approach here.

#### Missing `by` clause

```
routelist = data.table(id = 1:3, node_list = list(1:6, 4:7, 1:10))
item <- 5:8
routelist[, sum(item %in% unlist(node_list)) == length(item)]
```

returns a single `TRUE` value because

```
routelist[, unlist(node_list)]
```

returns a single vector

> ```
>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  4  5  6  7  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
> ```

If grouped by `id`, we do get the desired result:

```
routelist[, sum(item %in% unlist(node_list)) == length(item), by = id]
```

> ```
>    id    V1
> 1:  1 FALSE
> 2:  2 FALSE
> 3:  3  TRUE
> ```

or

```
routelist[routelist[, sum(item %in% unlist(node_list)) == length(item), by = id]$V1]
```

> ```
>    id    node_list
> 1:  3 1,2,3,4,5,6,
> ```

#### `%in%` checks only appearance but not the order

The expression `sum(item %in% unlist(node_list)) == length(item)` doesn't take care of the order of elements in `item`.

As order of the elements is important, the expression

```
isTRUE(all(diff(match(item, unlist(node_list))) > 0))
```

accounts for the order. `match()` returns the positions of the elements of `item` in `node_list` (or `NA` if not found). If the order in `item` is the same as in `node_list` then all differences in position must be positive. `isTRUE()` is required to cover the `NA` case.

Thus,

```
item <- c(5, 7, 8)
routelist[routelist[, isTRUE(all(diff(match(item, unlist(node_list))) > 0)), by = id]$V1]
```

returns

> ```
>    id    node_list
> 1:  3 1,2,3,4,5,6,
> ```

despite the gap while

```
item <- c(5, 8, 7)
routelist[routelist[, isTRUE(all(diff(match(item, unlist(node_list))) > 0)), by = id]$V1]
```

returns

> ```
> Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: id,node_list
> ```

as requested due to the wrong order.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions from `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

If the order is not important, the following approach may work. By examining the `id` column in `routelist2`, it is clear that id 3 is the one with the right condition.

```
# Create example dataset
library(data.table)
routelist=data.table(id=c(1:3),node_list=list(c(1:6),c(4:7),c(1:10)))
item<-c(5:8)

# Solution 1
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

routelist2 <- routelist %>%
  unnest() %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(all(item %in% node_list)) %>%
  nest()

routelist2 
# A tibble: 1 x 2
     id              data
  <int>            <list>
1     3 <tibble [10 x 1]>
```

If the order is important, we may have to convert the route numbers to string than find the right string pattern. The following approach should work.

```
# Solution 2
item_str <- toString(item)

routelist3 <- routelist %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(node_list = toString(node_list)) %>%
  filter(grepl(item_str, node_list)) %>%
  ungroup()

routelist3
# A tibble: 1 x 2
     id                     node_list
  <int>                         <chr>
1     3 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
```

#### Update

The following considering the situation when nodes in `item2` are not complete.

```
# Solution 3
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

item2 <- c(5, 7, 8)

routelist4 <- routelist %>%
  unnest() %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(all(item2 %in% node_list)) %>%
  filter(node_list %in% item2) %>%
  summarise(node_list = toString(node_list)) %>%
  filter(node_list == toString(item2))
routelist4
# A tibble: 1 x 2
     id node_list
  <int>     <chr>
1     3   5, 7, 8
```

Comment: i ve been working on it. indeed order is important, just realized. the second method didnot work by the way. I will try to convert the list to a single character string and then check equailty.

Comment: @volkang When you said it did not work, are you saying that it did not work on the example dataset you provided, or it did not work on your real-world dataset?

Comment: @volkang I realized that I missed one line in my second method. Please see my update. `item_str <- toString(item)` will convert the numeric sequence to a string. It is necessary to preserve the order.

Comment: thanks. now it works but partly. for instance if we have item<-c(5,8,9) it s not giving me the row

Comment: @volkang Are you saying route `item<-c(5,8,9)` should match `id 3`? This is different than what your original question specified. I would consider it to be a new question.

Comment: @volkang I will work on your updated question a little bit, but please note that this is not ideal to change your question after someone has already provided an answer because that person has no obligation to change the original answer if it works for the original question.

Comment: yes sorry, i realized afterwards. by the way, I came up with a solution with loops again, but still didnot like it. I m adding it as a different answer

Comment: @volkang Please see my update. This should consider the situation when nodes are not complete in `item`.

Answer (score 0):

Using loop (which is not elegant) it is possible to use the following check in the body. It does take order into account:

```
library(data.table)
routelist=data.table(id=c(1:3),node_list=list(c(1:6),c(4:7),c(1:10)))
item<-c(5,8,7)

for(i in 1:nrow(routelist))
{
  if(identical(intersect(unlist(routelist[i]$node_list),item),item)){
    print(routelist[i])  
  }

}
```